# Check whether or not an option exists in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm loading select2 into an `<input>` element, so I can't check the DOM for an `<option>` with a specific value. Is there any way to check whether or not value 2 for example exists inside the select2?

Comment: How do you load the select2?

Comment: @Tobia `$("#inputElem").select2({ data: function() { return results: dataArray; } });` where `dataArray` is dynamically filled with an Ajax call. However said array is inside a function that I can't do anything about, so I can't just save it for later checks.

Answer (score 0):

While the select2 dropdown menu is opened you can look for `$(".select2-results")` list elements. However it will be empty when the dropdown is closed.

Otherwise you can use the same "data" function of select2 and look into the result of your ajax call.

I don't think select2 stores the last result inside its data, but you can check: `$("#inputElem").data("select2")`